# ocaml loop count wihout using ref count?

Tags: ocaml

I am using a `ref` count to count how many times the function executes, but what if I want to get rid of the ref? I'm a noobie to ocaml, please give me some advice, here is what i got:

```
let count =ref 0;;  
let rec addtive n=
if n<9 then count 
else(
     incr count;
     addtive(sum(digit(n)))
) ;;

# a 551515;;
- : int ref = {contents = 2}
```

but i want to get like

```
-: int = 2
```

Comment: "but i want to get like

-: int = 2" just change `... then count` to `... then !count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the count around as a second parameter (defining a helper method if necessary):

```
let additive n =
  let rec helper n count =
    if n<9 then count
    else helper (sum (digit n)) (count + 1)
  in
  helper n 0
```

Comment: what a_helper in here, i have 3 function call in that function, a, s, d

Comment: i should make it loos better, i have ediited

Comment: @user1968057 I've defined a helper method, so that the `a` method still takes only one argument. If that's not necessary, you don't need the helper.

Comment: should a_helper be helper?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a typo. I've fixed that just now.

Comment: thx , its working now but can you just briefly explain the count in the helper function? im very new to ocaml, or you have some good website about ocaml?

Comment: Instead of mutating a variable you pass the new value in the function parameter with recursion (notice the let rec). When the condition to terminate is true you return the value. This is a general technique in OCaml so you should get very familiar with it. Make helper a toplevel function and call it with #trace if it's still not clear.

Comment: @user1968057 This is not specific to OCaml. All I did was to define a helper function that takes two parameters instead of one and passed the count around as the second parameter. The 1-argument function then called the 2-argument function with 0 as the argument. In C-like languages, that would look like this: http://codepad.org/tQetnwvI

Answer (score 3):

Just add a `!` in the `then` clause to extract the value from the `ref` :

```
let count =ref 0;;   
let rec addtive n= 
  if n<9 then !count
  else(
    incr count;
    addtive(sum(digit(n)))  
  ) ;;
```